# Ubuntu 16.04 login loop after changing dpkg-reconfigure

Tags: ubuntu, python

I was following this [DaVinci ezsdk installation tutorial Da vinci](https://welldoneblog.fedevel.com/2011/09/19/c6a816x-installation-host-machine-linux-kernel-compilation/).

After installing ezsdk I thought that I could restart to retrieve the shell's original settings because the first step was to do

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

I chose NO in the subsequent window, and after restarting I couldn't login to my PC!

While i was investigating the issue I saw this message in the terminal when I was trying to install Unity 8:

```
cannot import name _gi ubuntu
```

I determined that the cause is that a folder named `apt-pkg` was missing in Python 3.7 so I have changed it to use Python 3.5.

So far I haven't been able to solve the issue. I have tried to reinstall the LightDM desktop manager but it didn't work for me.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: A tutorial from 10 years ago is well past its due date. Ubuntu 16.04 as well unless you have extended support (ESM). And in any case messing with python breaks the system, end of story.

Comment: the thing is i didn't thought that it will effect the python links. and now the symptoms of the issue is the login loop so do you have any suggestions?